# Python find value in String

Tags: python, string, csv

I have to find some values in a CSV. Therefore I read the value of the column I need in a string. 
The strings I obtain can be like this:

```
String1 : "0;0;0;36480;0;0;0"


String2: "809;623;215;36188;420;418;65"
```

I just need the 4th value of each string (36480 , 36188)

I there a way to count the ";" in a string and save the values between the 3 and 4 ";"

I tried with string.find but I am not able to get the values I need...

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason you didn't use `split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.split` method to split the string to a list. And then use the  `index` to get the required element.

**Ex:**

```
String1 = "0;0;0;36480;0;0;0"
print(String1.split(";")[3])
String2 = "809;623;215;36188;420;418;65"
print(String2.split(";")[3])
```

**Output:**

```
36480
36188
```